# Asymptotic behaviour of heat equation solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, summation, heat-equation

In our lecture we discussed the solutions to
\begin{cases}
u_t - u_{xx} = 0, & x \in (0,1)   \\
u_x(0,t) = u_x(1,t) = 0, & t > 0 \\
u_x(x,0) = u_0(x) \in L^2(0,1)
\end{cases}
and found
$$
u(x,t)
= \frac{B_0}{2} +  \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} e^{- \pi^2 k^2 t} B_k \cos(\pi k x),
$$
where the $B_k = \int_{0}^{1} u_0(x) \cos(\pi k x) dx$.

To find the asymptotic behaviour we examined
$$
K
 := \left| u(t,x) - \frac{B_0}{2} \right|
= \left|  \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} e^{- \pi^2 k^2 t} B_k \underbrace{\cos(\pi k x)}_{\le 1} \right|
 \overset{(\star)}{\le} \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} B^2_k \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} e^{- \pi^2 k^2 t} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}},
$$
using Cauchy-Schwartz in $(\star)$.

By Parsevals identity we concluded $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} B^2_k  = \| u_0 \|_{L^2(0,1)}$. Until this point everything is clear.

> But now we concluded
>   $$
> K
> \le \| u_0 \|_{L^2} \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(e^{- t^2} \right)^{k} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
> = \| u_0 \|_{L^2} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1 - e^{-t^2}} \right)
> \xrightarrow{t \to \infty} 0.
> $$
>   There seem to be many mistakes, beginning with the absence of $\pi^2$ and $\| u_0 \|$ instead of $\| u_0 \|^{\frac{1}{2}}$, which I can't explain, but which are probably typos.
>   My question really concerns the second sum.
>   I know that for $|r| < 1$ we have $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} r^k = \frac{r}{r - 1}$ and that $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} r^{(k^2)}$ can only be written with the complicated [Jacobi Theta functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html), which our instructor probably didn't have in mind.
>
> How can this sum be estimated instead?

**Update 1**
Plotting with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%2F2%20%CF%91_3(0,%20e%5E(-%CF%80%5E2%20t))%20-%201%2F2%20and%20-(1%20-%201%2F(1%20-%20e%5E(-%20pi%5E2%20t)))%20from%20t%20%3D%200%20to%201) reveals that probably
$$ \tag{$\star$}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} e^{- \pi^2 k^2 t}
\le -\left(1 - \frac{1}{1 - e^{- \pi^2 t}}\right)
= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(e^{- \pi^2 t}\right)^k,
$$
indicating that the above inequality maybe correct up to the sign and the typos mentioned above.
How would one show ($\star$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because for $t>0$ and $k\in \Bbb N$, we can write $$\pi^2k^2t\ge \pi^2 kt$$and since the function $g(w)=e^{-w}$ is strictly decreasing over $\Bbb R$, we obtain$$e^{-\pi^2k^2t}\le e^{-\pi^2kt}$$which yields to what we wanted to show $\blacksquare$